# Interacting with Docker Image through ElasticBeanStalk

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are using AWS ElasticBEanStalk for creating our environment. We have already built our docker images and stored those in ECR repository. In ElasticBeanStalk, We ElasticBeanStalk we preovide Dockerrun.aws.json we provide image name. Everything works absolutely fine untill we decided that while creating EB environment we will pass one configuration file which will effect running Docker image. I am not very sure how we can pass this configuration file through eb create command to running docker.

Answer (score 0):

```
eb config
```

This will open up your saved configuration for this particular eb environment in a text editor. You can change the configurations, save and exit the file. This would immediately be applied to the eb environment and running docker instance.